# Priorityqueue implemented via singly linked list insert

Tags: java, data-structures, queue, priority-queue

I'm using a generic linked list to implement priority queue where I use the comparable function for the insert function where it finds a slot where it's size is bigger than the current node. I have problem actually getting the add function insert the elements according priority queue requirements. The priority queue should go from smallest to biggest.

Edit: I realize the problem lies with inserting a number bigger than the head. During add 11, the function only compares with 5 and add it after 5 which ruins the sequence.

Current output

```
PQ: 5
PQ: 5,10 
PQ: 5,9,10
PQ: 5,11,9,10
PQ: 5,7,11,9,10
PQ: 2,5,7,11,9,10
```

Desired output

```
PQ: 2,5,7,9,10,11
```

My add function

```
public class PQLinkedList<T extends Comparable<T>>{

private class Node{
    private T data;
    private Node next;


    // Constructor that takes in data to input for the node
    public Node(T data) {
        this.data = data;
        this.next = null;
    }
}


private int length = 0;
private Node head;
int cmp = 0;
public PQLinkedList() {
    head = null;
}

//Compare with each element till it finds a suitable position to insert itself
//Ascending order
//INCOMPLETE
//Compare part of this code is not complete!
public void addPQ( T data) {
    Node node = new Node(data);
    Node temp2 = null;

    if ( head == null) {
        addFirst(data);
    }

    else {
        Node curr = head;
        int count = getSize();


        while ( count != 0) {    

            cmp = data.compareTo(curr.data);


            if ( cmp < 0 ) {
                addFirst(data);
                break;
            }
            else if (cmp>=0 ){         
                if ( curr.next == null) {
                curr.next = node;
                break;
                }
                // if there curr.next is not empty
                // Move all the nodes towards to tail by 1
                else {

                    // after = one space after pos
                    // PROBLEM
                temp2 = curr.next;
                  Node after = curr.next;
                    while( after != null) {
                        after = after.next;
                    }
                    node.next = temp2;    
                    curr.next = node;
                    break;
                }


            }



            else {
            curr = curr.next;
            }
            count--;
        }
    }
    length++;

}





private void addFirst(T data) {
    Node node = new Node(data);
    if ( head == null ) {
        head = node;
    }
    else {
        Node temp = head;
        head = node;
        node.next = temp;
    }
    length++;
}

//TO-DO
public void remove( T data) {
    if ( !search(data)) {
        System.out.println("Linked list does not contain that element!");
        return;
    }
    else if ( head.data == data) {
head = head.next;
    }

    else {
        // If curr is the node to be deleted.
        // link from previous node to curr, link from curr to next node
        //Traverse through the linkedlist till it finds the node to be deleted and skip it
        Node curr = head;
        while ( curr != null & curr.next != null ) {
            if ( curr.next.data == data) {
                //Check if the node 2 next after curr is null
                //if so, remove curr.next which contains the value that we want to delete
                if ( curr.next.next != null) {
                    curr.next = curr.next.next;
                }
                //curr.next.next is null so just curr.next which contains the value we want to delete
                else {
                    curr.next = null;
                }
            }
            //Traverse the curr node
            else {
                curr = curr.next;
            }

        }
        length--;
    }
}


// Retrieves and removes the head of the priority queue
public T poll() {
    if ( isEmpty()) {
        System.out.println("Linked list is empty!");
        return null;
    }
    else {
        Node temp = null;
        temp = head ;
        head = head.next;
        length--;
        return temp.data;
    }

}

// Retrieves the head of the priority queue
    public T peek() {
        if ( isEmpty()) {
            System.out.println("Linked list is empty!");
            return null;
        }
        else {
            return head.data;
        }

    }

    public void clear() {
        Node curr = head;
        while ( curr != null) {
            curr = curr.next;
        }
    }


public int getSize() {
    return length;
}



public boolean search(T data) {
    if ( isEmpty()) {
        System.out.println("Linked list is empty!");
    return false;
    }
    else {
        Node node = head;
        while ( node != null ) {
            if ( node.data == data) {
                return true;
                }
            node = node.next;
        }
        return false;
    }
}


public boolean isEmpty() {
    if ( length == 0) {
        return true;
    }
        return false;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    String str = "PQ: ";
    Node node = head;
    while ( node != null) {
        str = str + node.data;
        if ( node.next != null) {
            str = str + ",";
        }
        node = node.next;

    }
    return str;
}
```

}

My main

```
public class priorityQueueImplementation {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    PQLinkedList<Integer> test = new PQLinkedList<Integer>();
    test.add(5);
    test.add(10);
    test.add(9);
    test.add(11);
    test.add(7);
    test.add(2);

    System.out.println( test.toString());


}

  }
```

Comment: I recommend taking a look at the MInPQ implementation from sedgewick: https://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/24pq/MinPQ.java.html

Comment: Maybe also include your `addFirst()`?. And we cannot see how the "generic linked list" is utilized in your queue.

Comment: If your outer loop is "Traverse down the priority queue till it finds the data to be bigger than the node's data", what is the purpose of the inner loop? Since is getting the last element.

Comment: @Mr.Brickowski Outer loop traverse down. Inner loop compares and find the appropriate position to input the data

Comment: You might consider adding the linked-list tag, since your real problem is with linked list operations rather than priority queue.

Answer (score 0):

Since this is a singly linked list, we cannot add node to previous node. We can only add to subsequent node. During node insertion, we need to compare `data` with the list. One every node, there are 5 cases:

1. `current` is null, `data` become the new head
2. `data` is smaller than `current`, `data` become the new head
3. `data` is greater than `current`, `data` is smaller then `next`. Insert `data` between `current` and `next`
4. `data` is greater than `current`, `next` is null. Insert `data` after `current`
5. `data` is greater than `current`, `data` is greater then `next`. Wait for next iteration

```java
    public void addPQ(T data) {
        Node node = new Node(data);

        Node curr = head;

        if (head == null) {
            // current is null, data become the new head
            addFirst(data);
        } else {

            while (curr != null) {
                int cmpLeft = data.compareTo(curr.data);

                if (cmpLeft < 0) {
                    // data is smaller than current, `data` become the new head
                    addFirst(data);
                    break;
                } else {
                    // data is greater than current
                    if (curr.next == null) {
                        // next is null. Insert `data` after `current`
                        addAfter(curr, node);
                        break;
                    } else {
                        int cmpRight = data.compareTo(curr.next.data);
                        if (cmpRight < 0) {
                            // data is smaller then next. Insert data between current and next
                            addAfter(curr, node);
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    // data is greater then next. Wait for next iteration
                    curr = curr.next;
                }

            }

        }

    }

    private void addAfter(Node currNode, Node newNode) {
        if (currNode == null) {
            currNode = newNode;
        } else {
            Node tempTail = currNode.next;
            currNode.next = newNode;
            newNode.next = tempTail;
        }
        length++;
    }
```

output

```
PQ: 2,5,7,9,10,11
```